# why does it skips the first line for input of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, raw-input

Input Format

The first line contains the space separated values of N
and M.
The next lines contain the space-separated elements of columns.

```
input
2 2
1 2
3 4
```

the code

```
import numpy


my_array = numpy.array([input().split() for _ in range(int(input().split()[0]))],int)

print(my_array.T,my_array.flatten(),sep = "\n")
```

while taking input for the array how the code skips the first line "2 2" containing number of rows and number of columns,
i just want an understanding of how it starts taking input from the second line

```
output
[[1 3]
 [2 4]]
[1 2 3 4]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the `for _ in range(int(input().split()[0]))` gets executed and the first line (in your sample input, `2 2`) is read from the input. Then for the range obtained from the executed `range(int(input().split()[0]))` the next lines would be read.
In your sample input, first the `for _ in range(int(input().split()[0]))` will be executed, which is actually `for _ in range(2))` and then the *2* next lines will be read with `input().split()`.

Answer (score 1):

This code uses list comprehension, in which the call of the latter `input()` reads the first line, so that it takes input from the second line.

This code is equivalent to:

```py
import numpy as np

# Read the first line.
num_rows = int(input().split()[0])

# Deal with data.
rows = []
for __ in range(num_rows):
    rows.append(input().split())
my_array = np.array(rows, int)

print(my_array.T, my_array.flatten(), sep='\n')
```